# Configuring Apache, PHP5 FPM and MySQL for long Query

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    a.`id_order`,`reference`,`total_paid_tax_incl`,
    `payment`,a.date_add as date_add, 
    a.id_currency, a.id_order AS id_pdf,
    CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), '. ', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
    osl.`name` AS `osname`, os.`color`,
    IF((SELECT COUNT(so.id_order) FROM `ps_orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer) > 1, 0, 1) as new,
    IF(om.`erp_order_id` is null, 0, 1) as erp_id
FROM `ps_orders` a
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_merge` om ON (om.`prst_order_id` = a.`id_order`) 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY a.id_order DESC LIMIT 0,50;
```

Which took about 160 seconds to load. This query is called on a very specific page (in fact only being called from one particular page). Let's just assume the following URL execute such query:

http://example.com/some/url/query.php

At the moment when i call that query, the browsers shows

```
'500 Internal Server Error'
```

Upon further debugging, i get the following from the log:

```
Wed Mar 30 01:22:43.780576 2016] [fastcgi:error] [pid 12345:tid 1234567890] [client 123.459.78.123:12345] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/path/to/php5-fcgi", referer: http://example.com/some/file.php
```

And FPM slow log indicates this :

```
script_filename = /path/to/some/script.php
[0x00007f55bb18afd8] query() /path/to/some/script/DbPDO.php:80
[0x00007f55bb18aef8] _query() /path/to/some/script/Db.php:305
[0x00007f55bb18ad88] query() /path/to/some/script/Db.php:482
[0x00007f55bb18ab68] executeS() /path/to/some/script/AdminController.php:2198
[0x00007f55bb18a9e8] getList() /path/to/some/script/AdminController.php:1531
[0x00007f55bb18a8d0] renderList() /path/to/some/script/AdminController.php:1440
[0x00007f55bb18a788] initContent() /path/to/some/script/Controller.php:167
[0x00007f55bb18a5d0] run() /path/to/some/script/Dispatcher.php:349
[0x00007f55bb18a480] dispatch() /path/to/some/script/index.php:50
```

This is the exact file & lines that execute the query:

```
[0x00007f55bb18ab68] executeS() /path/to/some/script/AdminController.php:2198
```

I want to know how can i **extend the timeout** so that apache/php5-fpm will wait for at least 160 seconds. So that, at least for now; i can load that troubled page.

i already set my php.ini:

```
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.connect_timeout = 160
```

**EDIT 1**

I am not allowed nor i have access to modify the query.

Comment: Are you using `set_time_limit` in your PHP at all?

Comment: @apokryfos I can't find any 'set_time_limit' from the source code. And max_execution (in php.ini) has been set to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my own problem, i ended up noticing that one of the LEFT JOINED table was not indexed properly.

I created an Index for this table:

```
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_merge`
```

And the query runs a lot faster (less than a sec).